# Add to linked list (the util) without duplicates

Tags: java, linked-list

I am using this util: `import java.util.LinkedList;`  in Java. I was wondering if there is a way to add 2 Linked lists without allowing duplicates (like a set in python for example)  or is there a built-in function to remove duplicates from that util?

If the answer is no, is there a way to explicitly write a function that removes duplicates from this util?

Thank you!

Comment: Does "add 2 Linked lists..." mean "add to a linked list..." or "add two linked lists together (i.e., merge them)"?

Comment: Why don't you use a `java.util.Set` (like HashSet)? You can use set.addAll(collection) to add any Collection(a LinkedList is a Collection) to a Set.

Comment: @KevinAnderson merge them, but if for example l1 = [1,2,3] and l2 = [3,5] and I do l1.merge(l2); and so l1 would be [1,2,3,5] and l2 still remains [3,5] it's completely fine as well

Comment: Linked lists are inherently ordered collections.  You need to tell us the logic by which two linked lists are to be combined here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java 8` `stream` to get unique values.

```
new_list = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
  .distinct()
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here both `list1` and `list2` remains unmodified

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow duplicates and if you don't necessarily need to implement the java.util.List interface, you may want to consider using java.util.LinkedHashSet instead. This Set will keep the order of the elements and will not allow duplicates. If you have a list that you want to convert, just create a new LinkedHashSet using the LinkedList as a constructor parameter.

Iterating over the elements of the second list to check if each is contained in the first list is an expensive operation, so you will probably want to avoid doing that.

The main advantage of using LinkedHashSet will be that you get the Set functionality and keep the order of the elements. The main disadvantage of LinkedHashSet is that you can't query the set by element based on its position, as that is not a method defined in the Set interface and LinkedHashSet does not implement the List interface. Furthermore, in creating new objects, you will create a new list (or set) eventually and not modify the current one.

Assuming you have two LinkedList instances list1 and list2, you could do the following:

```
Set<?> linkedSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list1);
linkedSet.addAll(list2);
list1 = new LinkedList(linkedSet);
```

If you really just want to add to the instance of the first list, then you can do something similar:

```
Set<?> linkedSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(list1);
linkedSet.addAll(list2);
list1.clear();
list1.addAll(linkedSet);
```

Creating a LinkedHashSet is not an expensive operation, and the contains() method runs in constant time (i.e. does not depend on the size of the set), so checking whether elements are already contained in the original set doesn't normally take as much time, especially when your lists contain a lot of elements.